# how to use in css a mixed variable and string

Tags: css, variables

How can i mix a css-variable with a String-text like this Example:

```
@define {   site_path: http://www.xy.de/;}

body{
background:url(@site_path xy.gif);
}
```

thank you

Comment: You should have a look at Less or Sass

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not natively support variables. There are CSS "compilers" that can do this, generating static CSS files.

See:

http://lesscss.org/

snd

http://sass-lang.com/